# Regex to find at least one cyrillic character

Tags: regex, cyrillic

I want to find one or more cyrillic characters(а-я) within a string. So far i manage to find the character wherever it is except for the start of the string.

Expression that i'am using -> `^[\p{L}\d\s\-](.*[а-яА-Я].*)+$`

1. ok -> loremфффф ф
2. ok -> ipsuфmл
3. ok -> ffffл
4. ok -> фgfфdфg
5. ок -> ллlorem
6. fail -> лlorem (because the first letter is in cyrillic and it is the only one)

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Do you want to match only the cyrillic characters or the whole word containing a cyrillic  character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^\P{Cyrillic}*\p{Cyrillic}.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hilaYo/1).

If you want to only deal with Russian chars, you can replace `\p{Cyrillic}` with `[а-яёА-ЯЁ]` and `\P{Cyrillic}` with `[^а-яёА-ЯЁ]`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\P{Cyrillic}*` - zero or more chars other than Cyrillic
- `\p{Cyrillic}` - a Cyrillic char
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

To match multiline strings, add `(?s)` at the start, or replace `.`  with a `[\w\W]` workaround construct.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Thank you for the good explanation about the example, but i want also to 'catch' cases where the first letter is in cyrillic, like лdot, цfor etc.

Comment: @Denis You wrote *"fail -> лlorem (**because the first letter is in cyrillic and it is the only one**)"* so you can't want to match cases like  лdot, цfor, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I think he meant that HIS regex failed on that.

Comment: @Poul Bak, exactly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thak you so much. This is what i want to accomplish.